# Full calendar doesn't display proper end time in week and day view in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, rrule

I'm using full calendar v5 in angular https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/displayEventTime.
In this calendar end time is not displayed but i'm passing end time also and in week view and day view end time is not extended properly if it is a 2 hour event it is not positioned properly it seems like all the events and of 1 hours.

```
export class eventComponent implements OnInit {

 @ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent; 

  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    height:650,
    initialView: "timeGridWeek",
    scrollTime: this.currentdateTime,
  };

  ngOnInit() {
   loadCalendar()
  }

      loadCalendar(){ 
          let _self=this;
          this.calendarEvents=[];
          this.calendarOptions = {
            initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
            dateClick: this.onDateClick.bind(this),
            events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) { 
              _self.Service.getEvent(fetchInfo.startStr,fetchInfo.endStr,400).subscribe((res) => {
                if(res?.length>0)
                {
                  _self.calendarEvents=res; 
                  _self.lstEvents = _self.calendarEvents.map(x => {
                   let utcStarttime=new Date(x.when.start_time * 1000).toString();
                   let utcEndtime=new Date(x.when.end_time * 1000).toString();
                   if(x?.recurrence?.rrule[0] && x?.recurrence?.rrule[0]!=undefined)
                   {
                   return {
                     ...x,
                    start: moment(utcStarttime).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ'), 
                     startStr:moment(utcStarttime).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ'),
                     endStr:moment(utcEndtime).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ'),
                     end:moment(utcEndtime).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ'),
                     alldays:false,
                     rrule: 'DTSTART:'+moment(utcStarttime).utc().format('YYYYMMDDTHHmmss[Z]')+'\n'+x?.recurrence?.rrule[0],
                   };
                   }
                   else
                   {
                     return {
                       ...x,
                       start: moment(utcStarttime).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ'), 
                       startStr:moment(utcStarttime).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ'),
                       endStr:moment(utcEndtime).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ'),
                       end: moment(utcStarttime).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ'), 
                       alldays:false,
                     };
                   }
                  });
                  successCallback(_self.lstEvents);
                }
                else
                {
                  successCallback(_self.lstEvents);
                }
            });
            },
            eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
            headerToolbar: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
            },
            dayMaxEvents: 3,
            allDaySlot: false,
            weekends: true,
            editable: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectMirror: true,
            displayEventTime:true,
            displayEventEnd: true,
            height: 650,
            eventTimeFormat: { 
              hour: '2-digit',
              minute: '2-digit',
              hour12: true
            },
            plugins: [rrulePlugin,dayGridPlugin,timeGridPlugin, listPlugin,interactionPlugin],
            scrollTime: this.currentdateTime,
          };
      }
```

[image]

Please suggest some solution to fix this issue.

> ```
> Response:
> ```

```
{
"id":"457457457457",
"object":"event",
"title":"test event",
"description":"",
"read_only":true,
"when":{
"start_time":1687183200,
"end_time":1687186800,
"object":"timespan"
},
"busy":true,
"status":"confirmed",
"recurrence":{
"rrule":[
"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20230625T140000Z;INTERVAL=1"
],
"timezone":"Asia/Calcutta"
},
"original_start_time":null,
"reminders":{
"reminder_minutes":15,
"reminder_method":"popup"
}
},
```

using this package:

```
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/rrule": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.4.0",
```

> `Updated Cases:`

I tried to pass this as a start time **1687894200 (28th June 1:00 AM)** and end time **1690408800 (Thursday 27th July 3:30 AM)**

1. It is still displayed as 1 hour event only but it is  2:30 hrs event.
2. I passed this rule **RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20230725T193000;BYDAY=TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU** events are diplayed for monday also but tuesday it is not, Events should not display for Monday only
   showing event

pls check with this data :

```
var _self = {};
_self.calendarEvents = [];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: "timeGridWeek",
    //dateClick: this.onDateClick.bind(this),
    events: function (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
      var res = [
        {
          id: "457457457457",
          object: "event",
          title: "test event",
          description: "",
          read_only: true,
          when: {
            start_time: 1687894200,
            end_time: 1690408800,
            object: "timespan"
          },
          busy: true,
          status: "confirmed",
          recurrence: {
            rrule: ["RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20230725T193000;BYDAY=TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU"],
            timezone: "Asia/Calcutta"
          },
          original_start_time: null,
          reminders: {
            reminder_minutes: 15,
            reminder_method: "popup"
          }
        }
      ];
      if (res?.length > 0) {
        _self.calendarEvents = res;
        _self.lstEvents = _self.calendarEvents.map((x) => {
          let utcStarttime = new Date(x.when.start_time * 1000).toString();
          console.log ("utcStarttime:" + utcStarttime);
          let utcEndtime = new Date(x.when.end_time * 1000).toString();
          console.log ("utcEndtime:" + utcEndtime);
          if (x?.recurrence?.rrule[0] && x?.recurrence?.rrule[0] != undefined) {
            return {
              ...x,
              start: moment(utcStarttime)
                .utc()
                .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ"),
              startStr: moment(utcStarttime)
                .utc()
                .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ"),
              endStr: moment(utcEndtime)
                .utc()
                .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ"),
              end: moment(utcEndtime).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ"),
              alldays: false,
              rrule:
                "DTSTART:" +
                moment(utcStarttime).utc().format("YYYYMMDDTHHmmss[Z]") +
                "\n" +
                x?.recurrence?.rrule[0]
            };
          } else {
            return {
              ...x,
              start: moment(utcStarttime).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ"),
              startStr: moment(utcStarttime).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ"),
              endStr: moment(utcEndtime).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ"),
              end: moment(utcStarttime).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ"),
              alldays: false
            };
          }
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(_self.lstEvents));
        successCallback(_self.lstEvents);
      } else {
        //successCallback(_self.lstEvents);
      }
    },
    //eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek"
    },
    dayMaxEvents: 3,
    allDaySlot: false,
    weekends: true,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    displayEventTime: true,
    displayEventEnd: true,
    height: 650,
    eventTimeFormat: {
      hour: "2-digit",
      minute: "2-digit",
      hour12: true
    },
    scrollTime: this.currentdateTime
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a sanple of the event data you're talking about - show us the contents of the `res` variable please, in JSON format do we can re-use it to try and reproduce the problem, and write an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson I have added one sample object data can you please check, events are rendered but the end time is not displayed in event and the slots does not end at proper end time like if event is for 30 minutes it should mark correct end time but in my can all the event are for 1 hours

Comment: Thanks. So what exactly were you expecting to see in the calendar, for this particular example? You seem to have provided data for an event with a 1-hour timespan. See the console log entries in this demo I made: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/yLQgmqN

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the example, can you please check the above updated block in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, regarding the duration of your events:

As far as I can see, `end` is ignored when using rrule, because the end date is specified in the rrule string. Therefore it will not take the end time and work out the duration from that property, either.

As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/rrule-plugin you must specify a `duration` instead for the events. The documentation for `duration` says:

> Must be something that parses into a Duration. If not specified, each
> event will appear to have the default duration.

So instead of setting `end` you need to calculate the difference between the start and end times, and use that as the duration. The example data you've supplied makes this more complicated because the two dates are not even same day - the end date is before the start date!! So we have to extract just the times first, and use those. Luckily momentJS can help us with this.

Your code is also setting some other properties that fullCalendar does not need (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/event-parsing for a list of what is recognised), and moment can parse your timestamps directly without needing a Date object first.

Therefore your event-processing code can be re-written as follows:

```
  if (res?.length > 0) {
    _self.calendarEvents = res;
    _self.lstEvents = _self.calendarEvents.map((x) => {
      let utcStart = moment.unix(x.when.start_time).utc();
      let startTime = moment();
      startTime.set({ "hour": utcStart.hour(), "minute": utcStart.minute(), "second": utcStart.second() });
      console.log ("utcStart:" + utcStart.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"), startTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));

      let utcEnd = moment.unix(x.when.end_time).utc();
      let endTime = moment();
      endTime.set({ "hour": utcEnd.hour(), "minute": utcEnd.minute(), "second": utcEnd.second() });
      console.log ("utcEndtime:" + utcEnd.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"), endTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));

      if (x?.recurrence?.rrule[0] && x?.recurrence?.rrule[0] != undefined) {
        return {
          duration: moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime)).asMilliseconds(),
          rrule:
            "DTSTART:" +
            utcStart.format("YYYYMMDDTHHmmss[Z]") +
            "\n" +
            x?.recurrence?.rrule[0]
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...x,
          start: utcStart.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ"),
          end: utcEnd.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ"),
          allDay: false
        };
      }
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(_self.lstEvents));
    successCallback(_self.lstEvents);
  } else {
    successCallback(_self.lstEvents);
  }
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PoxmWLp

Secondly, regarding the problem you mentioned where it shows events on Mondays instead of Tuesdays, I could not reproduce that issue using your code. I don't think there is actually a problem to solve - maybe you should double-check what you were seeing. It could just be because you are passing the times to fullCalendar in UTC, and then your timezone translation means that the event moves over into the following day.

Comment: Thanks start time and end time is working i have added screenshot of the same codepen that i viewed on my system there i can see the event on Monday instead of Tuesday, is this issue due to UTC

Comment: What timezone are you in? I would expect that it probably is, because my timezone is GMT+1 and the events show as 8.30-11pm on the expected days, and in UTC the events are 7.30pm-10pm

Comment: My time zone is GMT +05:30

Comment: Well then, 5:30 hours after 7.30pm is 1am, and that is exactly what we see in your screenshot. So yes the behaviour you're seeing is simply related to the timezone. To avoid it, I think you would need to pass the events to fullCalendar already in the local time.

Comment: If i pass time in this format `let utcStart = moment.unix(x.when.start_time).local();` then `1:00 AM` is shown `6:30 AM` event in myside can you suggest some solution for this issue

Comment: Hm, have you tried using the dates just as-is, without the `.utc()` and also without the `.local()`?

Comment: i tried to remove `.local()` and `utc()` then events are shifted to `5:30 hrs` if events starts from `1:00 AM` it is shifter to `6:30 AM` event

Comment: Thanks. I think you would need to remove the `[Z]` from the rrule string as well. Because that is also telling the calendar to interpret the date as a UTC string, when it's not. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/BaGZMmv

Comment: For a wider discussion of how fullCalendar treats incoming dates in different formats, and how you can use the settings and the date formats to affect that, please read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeZone

Comment: yes i have checked `i changed the time zone to `timeZone: 'utc'` and `moment.unix(x.when.start_time).local()` and `moment.unix(x.when.end_time).utc();` then start time and end time is correct but if i unchecked monday it is showing event on monday and on tuesday it is off

Comment: It makes no sense to have the start time as local and the end time as utc. Why did you do all that? Why didn't you just remove the [Z] from the rrule format string like I mentioned above. I'd expect that should resolve the issue.

Comment: I checked your example but getting same issue, i have this `start time (1689024600)` and `end time (1689028200)` and this rrule `RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20230716T213000;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,SA,SU` which is returned from microsoft 365 calendar in my end it is not showing event 
on saturday instead it is showing on Friday this event end date is 17 July

Comment: That's not my experience - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/dyQJvzQ . The events show up at their UTC time, which is 22:30